# How to show a loading spinner for async requests in a React + Redux application?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a higher order component that displays a spinner when data is fetching from a server and the component with the data when it's done. However with the implementation I have done below it goes straight to rendering the component and not the spinner giving an error the it `can not read property length of null`.

I think the problem might be related to the initial state I am giving to the reducer with the `isFetching: false` property. When debugging the application the HOC `withSpinner` gets an `isLoading` prop as `false`. To test `withSpinner` HOC I set the `isFetching` initial state as `true`. This way it only displays a spinner and doesn't continue updating the component. The selected value `isFetching` from the reducer never updates to `false`.

Redux actions file

```
import ProductActionTypes from "./product.types";
import { DB } from "../../api/DB";

const fetchProductsStart = () => ({
  type: ProductActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_START
});

const fetchProductsSuccess = products => ({
  type: ProductActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: products
});

const fetchProductsFailure = errorMessage => ({
  type: ProductActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
  payload: errorMessage
});

export const fetchProductsStartAsync = (series, queryStrings) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchProductsStart());

    DB.Product.getFilteredProducts(series, queryStrings)
      .then(products => dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(products)))
      .catch(err => dispatch(fetchProductsFailure(err)));
  };
};
```

Redux reducer

```
import ProductActionTypes from "./product.types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  products: null,
  errorMessage: null,
  isFetching: false,
  totalResultsFromQuery: 0
};

const productReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ProductActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case ProductActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        products: action.payload[0],
        totalResultsFromQuery: action.payload[1][0].totalResultsFromQuery
      };
    case ProductActionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        errorMessage: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default productReducer;
```

I am using reselect to get the isFetching value from my redux store:

```
export const selectIsFetching = createSelector(
  [selectProducts],
  products => products.isFetching
);
```

The React Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { compose } from "redux";

import { fetchProductsStartAsync } from "../../redux/product/product.actions";
import {
  selectProductItems,
  selectIsFetching,
} from "../../redux/product/product.selectors";
import {
  selectCurrentPage,
  selectCapacity
} from "../../redux/filter/filter.selectors";

import withSpinner from "components/withSpinner/withSpinner";
import ProductItemCard from "components/ProductItemCard/ProductItemCard";

import "./ProductsWrapper.css";

import {
  selectSearchInput,
  selectColor,
  selectFamily,
  selectPriceFrom,
  selectPriceTo
} from "redux/filter/filter.selectors";
import { resetDefault } from "../../redux/filter/filter.actions";

class ProductsWrapper extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      fetchProducts,
      match: { params },
      color,
      searchInput,
      priceFrom,
      priceTo,
      family,
      page,
      capacity
    } = this.props;
    fetchProducts(params.seria, {
      color,
      searchInput,
      priceFrom,
      priceTo,
      family,
      page,
      capacity
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {
      fetchProducts,
      match: { params },
      color,
      searchInput,
      priceFrom,
      priceTo,
      family,
      resetFilterToDefault,
      page,
      capacity
    } = this.props;

    if (params.seria !== prevProps.match.params.seria) {
      resetFilterToDefault();
      fetchProducts(params.seria, {
        color,
        searchInput,
        priceFrom,
        priceTo,
        family,
        page,
        capacity
      });
    }

    if (
      color !== prevProps.color ||
      searchInput !== prevProps.searchInput ||
      priceFrom !== prevProps.priceFrom ||
      priceTo !== prevProps.priceTo ||
      family !== prevProps.family ||
      page !== prevProps.page ||
      capacity !== prevProps.capacity
    ) {
      fetchProducts(params.seria, {
        color,
        searchInput,
        priceFrom,
        priceTo,
        family,
        page,
        capacity
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { products } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="products-outer-wrapper">
        <div className="products-wrapper">
          {products.length !== 0 ? (
            products.map(({ ...productProps }, index) => (
              <ProductItemCard {...productProps} key={index} />
            ))
          ) : (
            <p>No products!</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  products: selectProductItems(state),
  isLoading: selectIsFetching(state),
  color: selectColor(state),
  searchInput: selectSearchInput(state),
  family: selectFamily(state),
  priceFrom: selectPriceFrom(state),
  priceTo: selectPriceTo(state),
  page: selectCurrentPage(state),
  capacity: selectCapacity(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchProducts: (series, queryStrings) =>
    dispatch(fetchProductsStartAsync(series, queryStrings)),
  resetFilterToDefault: () => dispatch(resetDefault())
});

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  ),
  withRouter,
  withSpinner
)(ProductsWrapper);
```

And the higher order component withSpinner:

```
import React from "react";

import Spinner from "../Spinner/Spinner";

const withSpinner = WrappedComponent => {
  const enhancedComponent = ({ isLoading, ...otherProps }) => {
    return isLoading ? <Spinner /> : <WrappedComponent {...otherProps} />;
  };

  return enhancedComponent;
};

export default withSpinner;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have noticed, you assign `products = null` in your default state, which is not a very good practice (imho). Why not assign `products = []` to get rid of the error in the first place? Also might be useful to use [PropTypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) to make sure products is always of correct type...